# Using ucanaccess console I get error: UCAExc:::3.0.2 user lacks privilege or object not found: DBO_TBLMATERIALS

Tags: ucanaccess

I've read the other instances of this issue and per the answers, I've verified that everything is spelled correctly and I've run the Compact and Repair tool.

The table I'm trying to access is a linked table and as you can see, it isn't listed as being loaded. If I select from one of the non-linked tables, the query is successful.

Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the console output:

```
C:\Temp\UCanAccess-3.0.2-bin>console.bat
Please, enter the full path to the access file (.mdb or accdb): C:\Work\Jira\SAP\SandboxDB.ACCDB
Loaded Tables:
Category List, Table1, Table2, Table3, Table4, Temp
Loaded Queries:

Loaded Indexes:
Primary Key  on Table3 Columns: (ID)
, Primary Key  on Table4 Columns: (ID)
, Primary Key  on Temp Columns: (ID)
, Index on Temp Columns: (ID)

UCanAccess>
Copyright (c) 2012 Marco Amadei
UCanAccess version 3.0.2
You are connected!!
Type quit to exit

Commands end with ;

use:
   export <pathToCsv>;
for exporting into a .csv file the result set from the last executed query

UCanAccess>select * from dbo_tblMaterials;
UCanAccess>UCAExc:::3.0.2 user lacks privilege or object not found: DBO_TBLMATERIALS

UCanAccess>
```

Comment: Restate your question at the start. Don't rely on the title.

Comment: What kind of external database is it?(access, xls...)

Comment: @jamadei - The "dbo_" prefix strongly suggests that it is an ODBC linked table referring to SQL Server. Still, it would be nice if Rich took the trouble to confirm this.

Answer (score 0):

An Access linked table named [dbo_tblMaterials] is almost certainly an *ODBC* linked table that points to a SQL Server table. UCanAccess uses [Jackcess](http://jackcess.sourceforge.net/) to read and write the Access database file, and Jackcess does not support reading ODBC linked tables.

If you really need to read/write ODBC linked tables in Access (as opposed to simply connecting directly to the SQL Server) then you'll probably have to build your application in C# and use `System.Data.Odbc`.